# Classes that use another class as a return type?

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have been reading my book on C++ and I have been doing pretty well so far, but in the last section I have read about just goes way over my head.

I understand return types, but how does a method use another class as a return type? When you do this are you creating an instance of the data variables and methods from the Point class? I am completely lost with the line: (not the const, or function definition just the concept stated above)

```
Point GetUpperLeft() const { return itsUpperLeft; }
```

However, this line makes perfect sense

```
Point itsUpperLeft;
```

Because, the class is creating the a class instance of a point with all the x and y coordinates. How does doing this with a function work is GetUpperLeft() an object that has an x and y coordinates too?

Here is the rest of the code.

```
// Begin Rectangle.h
2: #include <iostream>
3: class Point // holds x,y coordinates
4: {
5: // no constructor, use default
6: public:
7: void SetX(int x) { itsX = x; }
8: void SetY(int y) { itsY = y; }
9: int GetX()const { return itsX;}
10: int GetY()const { return itsY;}
11: private:
12: int itsX;
13: int itsY;
14: }; // end of Point class declaration
15:
16:
17: class Rectangle
18: {
19: public:
20: Rectangle (int top, int left, int bottom, int right);
21: ~Rectangle () {}
22:
23: int GetTop() const { return itsTop; }
24: int GetLeft() const { return itsLeft; }
25: int GetBottom() const { return itsBottom; }
26: int GetRight() const { return itsRight; }
27:
28: Point GetUpperLeft() const { return itsUpperLeft; }
29: Point GetLowerLeft() const { return itsLowerLeft; }
30: Point GetUpperRight() const { return itsUpperRight; }
31: Point GetLowerRight() const { return itsLowerRight; }
32:
33: void SetUpperLeft(Point Location) {itsUpperLeft = Location;}
34: void SetLowerLeft(Point Location) {itsLowerLeft = Location;}
35: void SetUpperRight(Point Location) {itsUpperRight = Location;}
36: void SetLowerRight(Point Location) {itsLowerRight = Location;}
37:
38: void SetTop(int top) { itsTop = top; }
39: void SetLeft (int left) { itsLeft = left; }
40: void SetBottom (int bottom) { itsBottom = bottom; }
41: void SetRight (int right) { itsRight = right; }
42:
43: int GetArea() const;
44:
45: private:
46: Point itsUpperLeft;
47: Point itsUpperRight;
48: Point itsLowerLeft;
49: Point itsLowerRight;
50: int itsTop;
51: int itsLeft;
52: int itsBottom;
53: int itsRight;
54: };
55: // end Rectangle.h

1: // Begin Rect.cpp
2: #include “Rectangle.h”
3: Rectangle::Rectangle(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)
4: {
5: itsTop = top;
6: itsLeft = left;
7: itsBottom = bottom;
8: itsRight = right;
9:
10: itsUpperLeft.SetX(left);
11: itsUpperLeft.SetY(top);
12:
13: itsUpperRight.SetX(right);
14: itsUpperRight.SetY(top);
15:
16: itsLowerLeft.SetX(left);
17: itsLowerLeft.SetY(bottom);
18:
19: itsLowerRight.SetX(right);
20: itsLowerRight.SetY(bottom);
21: }
22:
23:
24: // compute area of the rectangle by finding sides,
25: // establish width and height and then multiply
26: int Rectangle::GetArea() const
27: {
28: int Width = itsRight-itsLeft;
29: int Height = itsTop - itsBottom;
30: return (Width * Height);
31: }
32:
33: int main()
34: {
35: //initialize a local Rectangle variable
36: Rectangle MyRectangle (100, 20, 50, 80 );
37:
38: int Area = MyRectangle.GetArea();
39:
40: std::cout << “Area: “ << Area << “\n”;
41: std::cout << “Upper Left X Coordinate: “;
42: std::cout << MyRectangle.GetUpperLeft().GetX();
43: return 0;
44: }
```

Comment: Do you come from Java?

Comment: Also, Rectangle probably shouldnt store a point for each corner, its redundant and could get you in trouble. Also, members shouldn't be "itsXXX", they should be "myXXX".

Comment: It's C++ and the "its vs. my" debacle is completely based on opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `GetUpperLeft()` is called, a *copy* of `itsUpperLeft` is made, and handed to the caller of `GetUpperLeft()`.

You have not defined a copy constructor for `class Point` (did you get to copy constructors yet?), so C++ will define one for you.  The default copy constructor will just make a new instance of `class Point`, and put into it copies of all of the data members of `itsUpperLeft` (in this case just `x` and `y`).

**Edit:** In particular, if a caller runs code like:

```
Point my_copy = some_rectangle.GetUpperLeft();
my_copy.SetX(13);
my_copy.SetY(12);
```

there will be no effect on the values in `some_rectangle.itsUpperLeft`.

Answer (score 2):

`itsUpperLeft` is an instance of class `Point`.

`GetUpperLeft()`, in its current form, makes a copy of `itsUpperLeft` and returns that copy to the caller.

The caller can then call methods, such as `GetX()`, on that copy.